# SQlite JDBC - ResultSet value returns NULL

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I'm trying to display movie titles from the database, the problem is that if I call the `rs.getString()` method it always returns `null`. The database table is properly configured with one column/two rows and connected to the java application, so I don't know where the problem is..

This is my class which I call from the main function:

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {
    public Driver() {
        Connection c = null;
        
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
//            DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.sqlite.JDBC());
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
            
            Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
            
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Movies");
            
            rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));    // <---- prints null
           
            stmt.close();
            c.close();
            
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be several reasons e.g. `title` is a nullable field and has no value or `Movies` does not have any row. Did you execute `SELECT * FROM Movies` in a SQL client tool?

Comment: Yes, in that case the execution of the program is without errors and the result contains two rows containing the titles of the movies.
- Here is my database structure (where title is just a text field):

`Movies`
          **-** `title`
                   **-** `The Lord of the Rings,`
                      `Harry Potter`

Comment: What's the output you see when you replace `rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));` with `while(rs.next()){System.out.println(rs.getString("title"));}`

Comment: Well, that's interesting... I'm sure I've tried it before but it didn't return any value. But now it's showing the values just fine. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

3 things that seem weird:

1. you are using rs.next() before even using the first resultset.
2. it's not in a loop, meaning you'll only get the first result no matter how many rows there are
3. you are returning it in one string (getString) so I don't think it will return it properly.